# Elasticsearch exclude result

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

Hi i would like to exclude result who have inside two value

like

```
if ($type == 'doc' && $statut == 'inactive') 
            return false;
```

so i use bool like

```
$filter ['bool'] ['should'] ['bool'] ['must_not'][] = array (
        'term' => array (
                'type' => "doc"
        ),
        'term' => array (
                'statut' => "inactive"
        )
);
```

but that does not work can you help me

Edit: In clear i would like to exclude result have the type == 'doc' AND statut == 'inactive'

Comment: Hi, your title is really unclear, what does "must not if and" mean? What is the result you see with your current code?

Comment: edit is it more clear ?

Comment: Yes indeed! However, sorry I did not log on for a long time. Glad you could find your own answer, and good you provided it to others!

Answer (score 1):

I find

```
$filter ['bool'] ['must_not'] []  = array(
    'bool' => array(
        'must' => array(
            array('term' => array('type' => "doc" )),
            array('term' => array('statut' => "inactive")),
            ) 
        ) 
    );
```